# What are the different ways of simulating a keyboard input in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried multiple answers already, and none of them work.
Here's what I've tried :

- `element.value = '0'`
- `element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: '0' }))`
- `element.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', { key: '0' }))`
- Each of those followed by a call to `dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { buubles: true, cancelable: true }));`

What else can I try ? Some do update the field, but the content gets deleted immediately after.

Comment: It depends on what the code is listening for.

Comment: The important questions, are what is your end goal? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically